# вылетает приложение при добавлении данных в Firebase

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, firebase, firebase-database

У меня есть два фрагмента, один из них корзина и на нем стоит AddChildEventListener, то есть он постоянно слушает состояние БД и при добавлении данных в корзину, то есть со второго фрагмента, фрагмент корзины сразу пытается обновить список, а из - за того что за это время успевает придти только два поля в базу данных, вместо восьми, слушатель не может загрузить несуществующие данные и приложение вылетает. Как решить данный вопрос? Листинги ниже

Добавление в базу:

```
        String key = mReference.child("basket").push().getKey();
    mReference.child("basket").child(key).child("dishId").setValue(mList.get(position).id);
    mReference.child("basket").child(key).child("restaurantId").setValue(mList.get(position).restaurantId);
    mReference.child("basket").child(key).child("userId").setValue(userRef);
    mReference.child("basket").child(key).child("weight").setValue(mList.get(position).weight);
    mReference.child("basket").child(key).child("title").setValue(mList.get(position).title);
    mReference.child("basket").child(key).child("composition").setValue(mList.get(position).composition);
    mReference.child("basket").child(key).child("price").setValue(mList.get(position).price);
```

Слушатель:

```
private void updateList() {

    mReference.child("basket").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            mList.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(Basket.class));
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Basket model = dataSnapshot.getValue(Basket.class);
            int index = getItemIndex(model);
            mList.set(index, model);
            mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(index);

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Basket model = dataSnapshot.getValue(Basket.class);
            int index = getItemIndex(model);

            mList.remove(index);
            mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(index);
        }


        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Логи:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: 
main Process: com.food_good.lilsem.food_good, PID: 12371 
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference 
at com.food_good.lilsem.food_good.BasketFragment.getItemIndex(BasketFragment.java:115) 
at com.food_good.lilsem.food_good.BasketFragment.access$200(BasketFragment.java:25) 
at com.food_good.lilsem.food_good.BasketFragment$1.onChildChanged(BasketFragment.java:84) 
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzblz.zza(Unknown Source) 
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbnz.zzYj(Unknown Source) 
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzboc$1.run(Unknown Source) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5710) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:900)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
```

BacketFragment.java

```
public class BasketFragment extends Fragment implements BasketAdapter.OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener {


private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
private DatabaseReference mReference;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private List<Basket> mList;

private BasketAdapter mAdapter;

String userRef;

public BasketFragment() {

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.basket_list, container, false);

    Context context = getActivity();
    mList = new ArrayList<>();
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.basket_list);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    mAdapter = new BasketAdapter(mList, this);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    // получаем ссылку на пользователя
    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    userRef = user.getUid();

    updateList();

    return view;
}

private void updateList() {

    mReference.child("basket").orderByChild("userId").equalTo(userRef).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            mList.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(Basket.class));
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Basket model = dataSnapshot.getValue(Basket.class);
            int index = getItemIndex(model);
            mList.set(index, model);
            mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(index);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Basket model = dataSnapshot.getValue(Basket.class);
            int index = getItemIndex(model);

            mList.remove(index);
            mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(index);
        }


        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}


private int getItemIndex(Basket basket) {
    int index = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < mList.size(); i++) {
        if (mList.get(i).key.equals(basket.key)) {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return index;
}


@Override
public void onClick(int position) {

}
```

Comment: StackTrace с сообщением об ошибке в студию

Comment: Вверху написал. Кстати, если убираю слушателя во втором фрагменте, то не вылетает и добавляется нормально

Comment: код `BasketFragment` можно увидеть?

Comment: Добавил, опытным путем установил что вылетает в onChildChanged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В StackTrac'е написано, что в методе `getItemIndex()` класса `BacketFragment` Вы пытаетесь вызвать метод `java.lang.String.equals()` на пустой ссылке.

Более того указана строчка с проблемной строкой кода.

я подозреваю что это она:

```
if (mList.get(i).key.equals(basket.key)) {
    //...
}
```

Если исходить из описания ошибки, то скорее всего в одном из объектов `Basket` лежит переменная с пустым `key` и Вам необходимо перед сравнением проверить не является ли данная ссылка пустой.

Проще говоря:

```
if (mList.get(i).key!=null &&  mList.get(i).key.equals(basket.key)) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, еще поменял index на 1 в методе getItemIndex и все заработало

Comment: @ЕвгенийДементьев, отлично! Удачи Вам!